# Editing and automatically updating linked objects

Tags: linked-data

I'm currently attempting to link several .blend files into a main project file. The steps I have taken are as follows:

1. In main project file: *File > Link* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>)
2. Select .blend file to link
3. Select the scene data, so that all objects and material data are brought in
4. Data is now in separate scene within project. Select all, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to *Make links > Objects to Scene > Original scene* of main project
5. Select the objects that are now in the original scene and make proxy

There is one complication, however. If I wanted to edit the external file and save it, then close and reopen the main project file, I would not see any changes. For example, I tried scaling the external file, but there was no change in the main file. Short of getting external files right the first time around and not needing to ever edit them, is there some way these objects can remain editable from their original external files, while still retaining the ability to translate, rotate and scale?

Comment: One (not too simple) way - at least for transforms - could be this: add a new object (eg: en empty) and make it copy your proxy transforms (select first the empty, then add the proxy: go to object panel, right click on transforms, use "copy to selected" just once for transform type copies all axes). Then delete the proxy, and rebuild it. Lastly, do the opposite of before: copy the empty transforms to the new proxy.

Comment: Is 'rebuild' some sort of function, or are you referring to making edits to the external file? I'll assume the former, as my attempt to edit the external file did not work.

Comment: no, for rebuild, I meant: after you modify the external file object, apply transforms, and save. Then open the linking file: the proxy is still the same. Now delete the proxy, thus the linked object (from which you made the proxy) will get the source edits, instantly. Then you make again a new proxy from it. Having "stored" transforms in the empty before allows you to reapply them to the new proxy.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got it working. You're right in that it isn't exactly simple. This will definitely be a pain to do if I have a large number of duplicates and I need to edit the original file. I'm going to keep this question open for a bit, in case there might be other methods, but for now, I'll stick to your method.